# Get current class name in Intellij Idea plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to press key combination and get the fully qualified class name where the caret is at right now. I have deleloped a plugin but it required me to move the caret on to the class name.

```
PsiElement element = (PsiElement) e.getDataContext().getData("psi.Element");
element instanceof PsiClass {
    PsiClass className = element;
}
```

How do I get the class name when I press my key combination when the caret is in somewhere in the class ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType` to find the parent class like this:

```
PsiClass stmt = PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType(element, PsiClass.class);
```

Where `element` is the `PsiElement` currently under the caret (it seems you already know how to find it).

See [the source code of PsiTreeUtil](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/ideace/view/0d501e20a48b1536e09cebea0d7dd57fa43ebb27/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/psi/util/PsiTreeUtil.java;nav:21888:21903%3afocused;line:1033) for more info.